# vue component in Laravel project not update when I deploy to server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

I'm developing project using vuejs and Laravel. everything worked fine on my laptop and when I upload code to server (Digital Ocean) at that first time.

Otherwise, when I update some Vue component in `resources/components` folder and upload it to server again. It's seem component is not update on the server when I refresh the browser.

my code in \ webpack.mix.js is

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

and I try to run `npm run dev` or `npm run prod` on the server after I push the nw code on it as well. It doesn't work.

I also try to clear browser cache and reload url again, it doesn't work also.

Please give me an advice how should I do.

Regards.

Comment: Maybe try clearing laravel's cache on your production server.   `php artisan view:clear`    How are you loading your `app.js` script in you page / template?   if you are using something like this `<script src="{{ assets('js/app.js') }}"></script>`  since you are using `mix.version()` try loading it like this instead `<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Well its not a good idea to upload a laravel/vuejs project at shared hosting. Although doing such process can save your life.

1. Run php artisan serve view:clear
2. Do changes at your local file and then npm run watch.
3. after uploading all the changes to server, always replace public/css/app.css & public/js/app.js files.

Comment: Why is not a good idea? Too many developers only have a shared hosting where to work and they not decide (because customers decisions) that

Comment: well because of lots of time issues like caching or resource missing occurs. From my personal experience.